# File upload temp dir empty

Tags: php, upload

I am looking at how file uploads work in PHP.

When i upload a file, the `$_FILES` global says that the temp file name is `/tmp/phpDFUMAz` but this doesn't exist.

If i check ini settings for `upload_tmp_dir` I can see the following:

```
upload_tmp_dir  no value
```

What exactly is PHP doing here? It has given a temp file name to the uploaded file but that doesn't exist on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Temp files get deleted after the script that you uploaded them to is finished. The script that you uploaded them too needs to move the file out of the temp dir if you want to preserve it for later use.

Comment: Ok, so its moved temporarily and then when the script is finished executing these temp files are deleted?  Which part of the php process does this?

Comment: @MartyWallace you're looking for `move_uploaded_file()`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "which part of the php process does this". If you want more information about php file uploads, read this: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php